# Escape handling in popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, popup

I have a page at which when clicked on a button a popup appears and in that popup I have given a link which shows another popup . The problem here is when I handled the escape button in first popup , it worked fine . But when I am handling the escape button in second popup , when it is pressed both the popups are getting closed . But the need is if I press the escape button in second popup , only the second popup must close .Do anyone have the solution for this . 
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: No idea. We cannot see your code so it will all be guessing

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done with simple algorithm.

Define a variable, say `var currentPop = 0;`

When first pop-up is shown (or when first button is clicked) 
set it to 1, `currentPop = 1;`

When second pop-up is shown (or when second button is clicked) 
set it to 2, `currentPop = 2;`

Now, in the escape kay handling code: Write an algo. to hide appropriate pop-up.

```
function escapeHandling()
{
    if(currentPop == 2)
    {
        $("#secondPop").hide();
    }
    else if(currentPop == 1)
    {
        $("#firstPop").hide();
    }
}
```

*Provide me your code if you want exact fix!!!